# Is it possible to use history tracking with object fields in a report?

Tags: reporting, field-history

For example, record has a number field with a value that can vary a lot, and I want the history of that field on my report. The object is related to the Account and Product objects, so I'd like to have a report with results grouped by account and products and that lists the record changes through the specified date.

For example:

For the ACME account I'd like to know the amount of items in stock through September 2017, so it would list items like this:

> Product A - 4 units on 09/01/2017
>
> Product A - 0 units on 09/03/2017

So in this case the "product" is a lookup field on the object, but the quantity and date are history data on that same object.

Is this possible through the standard report builder, or should I create a custom Visualforce to display this?

Comment: when you go to reports --> new --> select report type and search for history, do you see object history with lookup object?

Comment: I see the option to create a report with the object's history, but I don't see an option of history + related object.

Comment: on the related object do you see "Enable reports" checked?

Comment: if you are looking for account with product history you may not get it out of box, you can export account/product history and vlookup in excel ( As a possible workaround to VF page look at powerquery/ power bi in 2016 version of excel. you can connect a salesforce org with excel even with 
 custom domain enabled and pull and massage data as required)

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get reports from both objects. Actually, I just opened the "object history" report, and I noticed that I can get the lookup fields (account and product), so this helps a lot already. The issue I'm now facing is that the change on unit amount needs to be related to another object, and I'm pretty sure this is not possible to do with history tracking in just one object.